# How to list all objects in a publicly available s3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am new to Amazon S3. When I open the s3 bucket link (which is public) in a browser, it is enlisting only a few objects inside it & not the complete list. So, how can I view all objects of a s3 bucket? Is there any add-on or extension or anything would help. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can use the awscli to make an unauthenticated [ListObjectsV2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListObjectsV2.html) request.

For example:

```
aws s3 ls s3://somebucket --no-sign-request
```

There is no guarantee, however, that the bucket policy will allow you to list the contents, in which case the response will be:

> An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: Access Denied